# How do I get the response from a RESTful API in VBA?

Tags: vba, rest

This is my first crack at calling a REST API from my VBA code.

The API documentation is located [here (PDF download)](https://connect.appointment-plus.com/docs/TechnicalGuide.pdf). I'm attempting to use the example on page 8 of the PDF just to ensure that everything is working fine with the exception of not providing a `location` parameter since I don't yet know what numbers they've assigned ours. Page 55 of the docs specifies that leaving this parameter off will return all locations, which is really what I'm after at the moment.

I've put together this code which seems to get me connected, but I don't seem to be getting the results the documentation promises.

```
Public Sub RESTtest()

  Dim URL As String
  URL = "https://ws.appointment-plus.com"

  Dim locationsURL As String
  locationsURL = "/Locations/GetLocations"

  Dim siteID As String
  siteID = "myID"
  Dim APIKey As String
  APIKey = "myKey"
  Dim restRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
  Set restRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
  Dim restResult As String

  With restRequest
    .Open "POST", URL & locationsURL, True
'    .Open "GET", URL & locationsURL, True
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & siteID & ":" & APIKey
    .setRequestHeader "response_type", "xml"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "application/xml"
    .Send
    .waitForResponse
    Debug.Print ".ResponseText: " & .ResponseText
    Debug.Print ".Status: " & .Status
    Debug.Print ".StatusText: " & .StatusText
    Debug.Print ".ResponseBody: " & .ResponseBody
  End With

End Sub
```

The `GET` gives me this output:

```
.ResponseText: <p>Welcome to the Appointment-Plus RESTful Web Service/API.</p><p><strong>ws.appointment-plus.com</strong></p>
.Status: 200
.StatusText: OK
.ResponseBody: ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

While the `POST` gives me this slightly less useful looking output:

```
.ResponseText: 
.Status: 200
.StatusText: OK
.ResponseBody:
```

In either case, I'm getting a status 200 which appears to be `OK`, so the call seems to be working just fine.

Looking through `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`, I see that there is a `.ResponseStream` which seems like a very likely candidate for getting the full XML of the response, however, it returns an IStream, which I haven't yet figured out how to handle in VBA.

Is `.ResponseStream` the proper property to get the full result of the API call and if so, what do I need to include in my project to enable me to handle it?

**UPDATE**

Based on this feedback that I received from the vendor:

> I would suggest he use Basic Auth instead of Strong and ensure the API Key and SiteID are sent in the request/header. Postman does this nicely.. I would also suggest the POST method and the parameters should be passed in the Body area of Postman(screen shots below).

I've gotten this to work via Postman with these settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I translate that into the code above? I've modified the `With` block to look like this:

```
  With restRequest
'    .Open "POST", URL & method, True
    .Open "GET", URL & method, True
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & siteID & ":" & APIKey
'    .setRequestHeader "response_type", "xml"
'    .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
    .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False
    .Send "{""response_type"":""xml""}"
    .waitForResponse
    Debug.Print ".ResponseText: " & .ResponseText
    Debug.Print ".Status: " & .Status
    Debug.Print ".StatusText: " & .StatusText
    Debug.Print ".ResponseBody: " & .ResponseBody
  End With
```

- Best I can tell, I was using Basic auth, not Strong, from the start, but, I'm new at this.
- I moved the `response_type` to the body, I think...
- I again tried both `POST` and `GET` and I still get the exact same results as last week. Postman will return valid results using `POST`, but `GET` returns exactly what my code is getting.